# Leveling up mundos w while using it, does the damage increase?

Tags: league-of-legends

Well let's take mundo's w or ulti. Would the damage of the w increase when you have it activated and you are leveling it up at this moment ? and if you activated his ult and you apparently hit lvl 11 and skill it up would you heal more for the rest of the duration ?

Comment: I wanna say yes to the W but no to the ult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes, since it is a toggled spell, the damage from Dr. Mundo's Burning Agony `W` does in fact scale up immediately. Dr. Mundo's ultimate (Sadisim) on the other hand, is a triggered skill. As such, when `R` is pressed, it applies a buff then is done. This means that the healing will not increase until the next time the skill is triggered.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_ability)